# Where can I ask for video game recommendations or suggestions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site to ask about video game suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange doesn't have a site for this, and it likely never will. We've [run into the great "Shopping recommendation" problem](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/?_ga=2.168053601.1100405633.1651180075-2050474202.1570125228) before.

If you were looking for places off-SE where you could find some recommendations, our Gaming site has compiled a [list of external resources](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13548/my-request-for-recommendations-was-closed-as-off-topic-where-can-i-ask-for-help) you can use.